# How to change the color of action bar menu in OnCreateActionMode()

Tags: android, android-menu

I am using below code to inflate menu

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.xyz_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }
```

How can I change the color of menu, right now its black I want to change it to some other color
Thank sin Advance

Comment: Menu bar or Menu item?

Comment: Check this https://www.codeandkits.com/Blog/2018/03/26/an-android-toolbar-and-action-bar-color-guide/